# Read text file and return double array

Tags: java, input

I need to write a method that reads the supplied filename and returns an array of doubles read from the file.

It can be assumed that the file only contains numbers in a single column, one number per line. If the file cannot be read or is not in the proper format it is OK to just return null.

How would one go about attempting this?

This is my attempt:

```
public static double[] fileRead(String filename) {
    double[] array = new double();
    // get some sort of reader here
    return array;
}
```

I dont know how to go on from here

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is give me code.

Comment: Probably you should attempt some "simplified code," then ask a question here (or ask your professor) when you get stuck on a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `ArrayList` and go on reading the file line by line. Convert the line into `Double` value and add it in to the `ArrayList`. If you couldn't read the file for any reason, return `null` from catch block.

```
public static Double[] fileRead(String filename) {
  List<Double> list= new ArrayList<Double>();
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
  try {
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            list.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
            line = br.readLine();
        } 
        return list.toArray(new double[list.size()]);
    } catch(Exception e){
         return null;
    }finally {
         br.close();
    }
}
```